# получить текущего пользователя в yml symfony4 (easyadmin)

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

```php
easy_admin:
  entities:
    User:
      class: App\Entity\User
      disabled_actions: ['delete']
      label: 'User'
      list:
          dql_filter: 'entity.id = %app.user.id%'<current_user_id><-- как это можно сделать?
          mapped: false
          actions: ['show']
          fields:
            - 'id'
            - 'email'
            - 'status'
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, почитав мануалы похоже в таком варианте возможности нет, сделал через контроллер (createListQueryBuilder)

```
class AdminController extends EasyAdminController
{
    protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = NULL, $dqlFilter = NULL)
    {
        $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass($this->entity['class']);
        $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('entity')
            ->from($this->entity['class'], 'entity')
            ->where('entity.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $this->getUser()->getId());

        if (!empty($dqlFilter)) {
            $queryBuilder->andWhere($dqlFilter);
        }
        if (null !== $sortField) {
            $queryBuilder->orderBy('entity.'.$sortField, $sortDirection ?: 'DESC');
        }

        return $queryBuilder;
    }
}
```